# "I felt sick from cold" vs "I felt sick due to cold"?

Tags: prepositions, synonyms

Under the entry for ***from*** in the [Oxford Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/from) is an example sentence:

> [sense] 13:
>
> ​  used to show the reason for something
>
> - *She felt sick from tiredness*.

Why not use ***due to*** instead of ***from***?

Is there any subtle difference between ***from*** and ***due to*** in such a context?

Comment: Maybe it's only idiomatic in the same vein as in the case of "suffering from disease". Also may be it's individual vs group thing as in "the society suffers due to malaria" or "the person suffers from malaria".

Comment: If you use **due to** your sentence will seems simple.

Comment: You could do. I'd almost always use 'She was so tired[,] she felt sick' in conversation. To my ears, using 'due to' here sounds a little over-formal for use in conversation, but works in a formal passage. 'Sick from tiredness' sounds unusual to my ears; the string gives a flatline in a Google ngram search, and a mere several thousand in a raw Google search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We tend to use *from* or *with* when the way a person is feeling is a likely, understandable result of their circumstances.

> He was shivering with cold.
>
> She felt weak from relief when she heard that her son was alive.

*Due to* sounds more formal, as Edwin says - like a medical diagnosis.

> The patient had breathing difficulties due to a chest infection.

Answer (score 0):

> "I felt sick from cold" vs "I felt sick due to cold"

Neither is idiomatic and I am not sure if you mean you have a cold or you are cold.

That said, tn the context given and assuming you are very cold, **from** indicates the origin, or original form, of the subject - *He came from London; it is made from steel*

**due to** indicates that its object is a cause - *The game stopped due to bad light. Due to carelessness, the ship was wrecked.*

The overlap of these meanings, i.e. where the origin is the cause, allows, in certain contexts, for either to be used.